# What makes Ctrl+Q work in zsh

Tags: zsh

I'm a zsh user who started off with a plain oh-my-zsh configuration and now I try to learn zsh by importing the parts I care about from oh-my-zsh into my own `.zshrc` and then completely remove oh-my-zsh.

When I now finally went cold turkey and removed oh-my-zsh I noticed that one of my most used shortcuts, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> has stopped working. I've investigated this and found the command to be called `push-line` according to [this source](http://www.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_14.html#IDX481).

I have no idea how to start using that ZLE feature though. I'm not even sure how to check if zle is running or not. I tried for hours to try to search the oh-my-zsh repository, but haven't found the command that activates `push-line`.

What do I need to do to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> working? What is it that oh-my-zsh does that I need to put in my own `zshrc`?

Comment: Ctrl-Q is usually the tty `start` character (opposite of Ctrl-S `stop`). You may have to disable those with `stty stop '^-' start '^-'` if you want to use them for other purposes.

Comment: Thanks @WumpusQ.Wumbley. You don't understand how much I appreciate this! If you make this and answer I'll upvote+accept you. (Othewise I will)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although I've never used the `push-line` feature, don't know what it does, and am afraid to even try to find out what "oh my zsh" means, any use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is likely to require unbinding it from the tty START function.

STOP (freeze output to the terminal) is normally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and START (unfreeze) is normally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. To remove those special characters,

```
stty start '^-' stop '^-'
```

Comment: You demonstrate great abstraction skills in solving this problem for me. As a return of the favor, I would like to invite you to try the `push-line` feature. I've found it so useful and saving me many seconds many many times a day! Thanks!

Comment: You can just unset with `stty stop undef` `stty start undef`

Answer (score 7):

One can also do

```
unsetopt flow_control
```

See: http://www.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_16.html

Comment: zsh seems to work with this, but for me vim does not recognize <C-q> binding. stty method worked well.

Comment: Thanks. `unsetopt` also works in `~/.zshrc`, which is not the case of the `stty` solution (producing the error `stty: stdin isn't a terminal`).

Comment: In case anyone's interested, this is the method that oh-my-zsh [uses](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/3e7998aec33ff7551d06d4510f9e8769aab5db93/lib/completion.zsh#L7).

Comment: This method works only if your shell is in emacs mode. It doesn't work if your shell is in vi mode, because vi-mode binds `^Q`  to `vi-quoted-insert`. You need to additionally run `bindkey '^Q' push-line` to get it working in vi mode.